# Openswan to Cisco ASA IPSec tunnel - specific IP address range required. Netmap?

Tags: nat, cisco-asa, ipsec, openswan

I'm attempting to set up a VPN tunnel between a Cisco ASA 5520 and an Openswan server running on Ubuntu 14.04 on a Amazon VPC instance.  I do not have access to the ASA, and have been given the following connection requirements from that end -

AES-SHA, No PFS, and our internal subnet (which is 10.0.0.0/24) must be presented to the Cisco side as a different range, 192.168.200.0/24.

These are the general configs I have in place -

ASA public - 1.2.3.4
ASA internal network - 192.168.50.0/24

Openswan EIP - 5.6.7.8
Openswan internal IP - 10.0.0.10
Openswan internal network - 10.0.0.0/24

Contents of /etc/ipsec.conf -

```
version 2.0     
# basic configuration  
config setup  
dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/  
nat_traversal=yes  
virtual_private=%v4:192.168.50.0/24  
oe=off  
protostack=netkey  
include /etc/ipsec.d/vpntunnel.conf
```

Contents of /etc/ipsec.d/vpntunnel.conf

```
conn vpntunnel  
type=           tunnel  
authby=         secret  
left=           10.0.0.10           
leftsubnet=     10.0.0.0/24         
right=          1.2.3.4               
rightsubnet=    192.168.50.0/24     
ike=            aes-sha             
pfs=            no  
auto=           start  
salifetime=     24h  
ikelifetime=    480m
```

Contents of /etc/ipsec.secrets

```
10.0.0.10 1.2.3.4 : PSK "mysharedkey"
```

The tunnel comes up fine as far as I can tell -

```
000 #137: "vpntunnel":4500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 83824s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#136; idle; import:not set  
000 #137: "vpntunnel" esp.80e09ea@1.2.3.4 esp.cb17c5db@10.0.0.10 tun.0@1.2.3.4 tun.0@10.0.0.10 ref=0 refhim=4294901761    
000 #136: "vpntunnel":4500 STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 26216s; newest ISAKMP; lastdpd=3s(seq in:0 out:0); idle; import:not set
```

I'm trying to tunnel from one specific server on the Openswan side to the ASA side, IP address 10.0.0.11.

On server 10.0.0.11 I've added the following route -

```
ip route add 192.168.50.0/24 via 10.0.0.10
```

The problem I'm having is getting the traffic from 10.0.0.0/24 to show up on the ASA side of the tunnel as 192.168.200.0/24.
From what I can tell, I should be able to use the following -

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.200.0/24 -s 192.168.50.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 10.0.0.0/24  
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.50.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.200.0/24
```

However, there is no traffic getting through the tunnel. Since the traffic going through the tunnel is only for 1 server, I would be fine with a specific IP NAT instead of a NETMAP, but those rules didn't seem to work either.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.50.0/24 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.11   
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.50.11
```

I've attempted to try to use KLIPS as well, to use the separate ipsec0 adapter, but have been unable to compile that properly.

As of now, my iptables are empty when I run the following command -

```
iptables -t nat -nvL
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?